# Need to filter certain UIWebView requests and load them in different UIWebViews

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

**Some Background**

I have an iPhone app with three UIWebViews, each used to show a different type of page. (The content is specifically designed for this purpose, they're not real web pages.) There are links associated with each specific web view. For example, a link tapped in WV1 might need to load in WV2 because it's a WV2-style link. (The webviews are in a paged UIScrollView, which I use to scroll to the currently loading webview. I can tell which URL loads where based on it's path.)

It makes sense to me to have a single UIWebView delegate that responds to all URLRequests (via `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`) and somehow decides which should load where.

The HTML I want to load in the webview isn't fetched directly from a page. I do something like `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]` to get the object, part of which is the actual HTML. (Additionally, this might come from the network or a local cache.)

**The Question**

I need to cancel a request in one UIWebView and then load some arbitrary data into another. How should I be doing the subsequent load, so that it bypasses my interception?

Should I stop all intercept all NSURLRequests via the webview delegate method, then send a new NSURLRequest, that will actually get loaded, to the correct webview? I was thinking I'd subclass NSURLRequest so I'd be able to tell original requests separate from my doctored requests. But again, I don't want to make straight NSURLRequests, I want to fetch an NSDictionary and use one of it's values as the HTML.

I saw this [article](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/) on filtering what loads in a UIWebView, but I don't think that's exactly what I want.

I'm trying to work my way through the [URL Loading System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html), but there's a lot there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using custom URL schemes to identify the requests that I wanted to load vs. the ones I wanted handled.

Comment: Here's [a more detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9827105/168594) of how I did this in response to a similar question.