# How can load an html page on iPhone webView without <img src=> tag

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I load a html page in web view in this way:

```
NSString *description = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mypage.html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:pRova baseURL:nil];
```

I need to remove:

```
<img src="http://www.mypage/image" align="left" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; width: 301px; height: 280px;" alt="diaspora-uys" />
```

from NSString *description, to display the UIwebView without image and with only text.
How can i do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "without tags"?

Comment: Sorry, i mean, i want load this page: http://www.abstract.it/news/diaspora-lopen-source-che-cambiera-la-rete/getText in uiwebview without display image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ load the HTML content in a string

`+(id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)`

2/ remove the `<img />` tag in the string

3/ use loadHTMLString on you webView

Have a look at [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Instead of finding the `<img />` tag in the HTML string, you can also perform a replace of `<img` by `<img style='display:none;'` to hide the image. But it will be still loaded...

Comment: You mean something like that: 
NSString *descrizione = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"html page"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *example = [example stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img / >"] withString:@""];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:descrizione baseURL:nil];

Comment: It looks good to me except the replace of `<img/>`. With your code, you will end with a broken HTML code. By `<img />` I was meaning the full `<img src="http://www.abstract.it/immagini-varie/diaspora-guys" align="left" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; width: 301px; height: 280px;" alt="diaspora-uys" />`. That's this complete tag that you need to skip.

Answer (score 3):

I solved in this way:

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {
    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *gt =nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        // find start of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<img" intoString:NULL] ; 

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&gt] ;
    }

    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", gt] withString:@""];
    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check that to apply filter on url scheme :
    [Need to filter certain UIWebView requests and load them in different UIWebViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358957/need-to-filter-certain-uiwebview-requests-and-load-them-in-different-uiwebviews)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code and it's working perfectly. It will only remove src value. Remaining values and image tag are not modified

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {
    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *gt = nil;
    NSString *temp = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        // find start of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<img" intoString:&temp]; 

        //find the src tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"src" intoString:&temp]; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:&temp];

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&gt];
        if (!gt) {
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&gt];    
        }

        if (gt) {
            html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",gt] withString:@"=\"\""];    
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```