# How to invoke Objective-C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In iOS, how can I call an Objective-C method from Javascript in a `UIWebView` and have it send data back to the Javascript? I know that this could be done on OS X using the Webkit library, but is this possible on iOS? How does PhoneGap achieve this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is an API to call JavaScript directly from Objective-C, *but you cannot call Objective-C directly from Javascript.*

### How to tell your Objective-C code to do something from the Javascript in your WebView

You have to serialize your Javascript action into a special URL and intercept that URL in the UIWebView's delegate's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

There you can deserialize that special URL and interpret it to do what you want on the Objective-C side. (You should return `NO` in the above `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method so the UIWebView doesn't use your bogus URL to actually make an HTTP request to load a webpage.)

### How to Run Javascript Code from Objective-C

Then you can run Javascript from Objective-C by calling this method on your webview.

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
```

## Example Code

I recommend using a bogus URL scheme so it will be easy to tell the difference between your action URLs and legit requests. You can make this request in the Javascript along these lines:

```
// JavaScript to send an action to your Objective-C code
var myAppName = 'myfakeappname';
var myActionType = 'myJavascriptActionType';
var myActionParameters = {}; // put extra info into a dict if you need it

// (separating the actionType from parameters makes it easier to parse in ObjC.)
var jsonString = (JSON.stringify(myActionParameters));
var escapedJsonParameters = escape(jsonString);
var url = myAppName + '://' + myActionType + "#" + escapedJsonParameters;
document.location.href = url;
```

Then in the `UIWebView.delegate`'s `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, you can inspect the URL scheme and fragment to check if it's a normal request or one of your special actions. (The fragment of a URL is what comes after the `#`.)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // these need to match the values defined in your JavaScript
    NSString *myAppScheme = @"myfakeappname";
    NSString *myActionType = @"myJavascriptActionType";

    // ignore legit webview requests so they load normally
    if (![request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:myAppScheme]) {
        return YES;
    }

    // get the action from the path
    NSString *actionType = request.URL.host;
    // deserialize the request JSON
    NSString *jsonDictString = [request.URL.fragment stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    // look at the actionType and do whatever you want here
    if ([actionType isEqualToString:myActionType]) {
        // do something in response to your javascript action
        // if you used an action parameters dict, deserialize and inspect it here
    }


    // make sure to return NO so that your webview doesn't try to load your made-up URL
    return NO;
}
```

(Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606842/168594) if you need help deserializing your json string into an NSDictionary.)

Comment: Great example. And from PHP you can encode like this:             `$fragment = array("key"=>"val"); $url = 'myApp://actionType#'.rawurlencode(json_encode($fragment));`

Comment: Should NSString *actionType = request.URL.path;  be  NSString *actionType = request.URL.host;  ?

Comment: I mean the in  "myScheme://myAction#jsonEscapedParameter"  URL.host should return *myAction* part.  Look at the documentation  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/host

Comment: @bluesm Yeah, that's a typo from my last edit. Fixed; thanks.

Comment: @zekel, the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method signature should end with a { not a semicolon!!

Comment: when should "- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;" be called?

Comment: @Yadnesh You can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to run Javascript code directly from your Objective-C code. For example, you could have a UIButton call that method to run some Javascript code in your UIWebView.

Comment: so this is for testing, and when in production ill put the same code on my webpage?

Comment: basically what goes in server for production env?

Comment: @Yadnesh This code isn't just for testing. The `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` lets you communicate from  ObjC -> Javascript. In order to communicate the other way, from Javscript -> ObjC, you must serialize the URLs in the method described above.

Comment: if you already have a url with fragment like http://www.google.com#1234 and you append #5678 to that like http://www.google.com#1234#5678 iOS won't recognise it...

Comment: I think now there is a better option: http://blog.impathic.com/post/64171814244/true-javascript-uiwebview-integration-in-ios7

Comment: Does Anyone know if this has ever ended in an rejected appstore review? Is the review somehow concerned about using this technique?

Comment: @Colonize.bat This approach is widely used and should not get you rejected. (Of course nothing in life is certain except death and taxes but I've been doing this for over five years with no issue whatsoever.)

Comment: @zekel Many thanks for this approach. I'm getting the following error:
error: The URL can’t be shown: [NSErrorFailingURLStringKey: myfakeappname://myJavascriptActionType#%7B%22name%22%3A%22AAPL%22%2C%22exchange%22%3A%22NASDAQ%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Apple%20Inc.%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22stock%22%2C%22interval%22%3A%22D%22%7D, NSLocalizedDescription: The URL can’t be shown, NSErrorFailingURLKey: myfakeappname://myJavascriptActionType#%7B%22name%22%3A%22AAPL%22%2C%22exchange%22%3A%22NASDAQ%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Apple%20Inc.%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22stock%22%2C%22interval%22%3A%22D%22%7D]

Comment: ive just had a problem of myAppScheme being passed to the objective c in lower case despite sending with upper case and checking against upper case. Just a heads up

Answer (score 12):

Changing page's location can cause several [issues](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/):

1. All setInterval and setTimeout immediatly stop on location change
2. Every innerHTML won’t work after a canceled location change!
3. You may get other really weird bugs, really hard to diagnose …

The solution, as offered [here](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/), is:

Keep using the same URL technique (on js and objective-c), just change the location with an iframe:

```
 var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
 iframe.setAttribute("src", "js-frame:myObjectiveCFunction";
 document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
 iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
 iframe = null;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Not working in iOS 10 please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43867801/3378413

Answer (score 5):

From Objective-C: You can pass a javascript function in a string to UIWebView. The web page will execute it and return a result. This way you can pass variables and get data back from Javascript.

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Example:

```
NSString *script = @"document.getElementById('myTextField').value";
NSString *output = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

From Javascript: Pass your data inside the URL. Intercept URL requests in UIWebViewDelegate. Get the data and abort URL request by returning NO.

```
<script>window.location = "url://key1/value1"; </script>
```

[Intercept the URL request](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```