# Reachability from link on webview

Tags: html, ios, webview, reachability

I have an html file in the resource bundle that is displayed in a webview.  There are links on the html page that access a website on the net. I want to check reachability each time a link is touched on the html page. How can I do this?

The iOS sample code for Reachability has a test for an html page directly.  How do I detect when a link is touched on an html page.  I am guessing this has something to do with setting the notification but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `<UIWebViewDelegate>` method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` will help you out. Implement it in your delegate, and perform your reachability test there, returning YES or NO as appropriate.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"loading %@", request);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have done this and the initial page in the bundle produces the same "no connection" error as a page on the web.  I want the first page NOT to check internet status and display from bundle.  Then I want to turn on the reachability testing.  I have not figured out how to bypass the shouldStartLoadWithRequest for the first page from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript function in HTML to know reachablity

```
function CheckOnlineStatus()
    {
        var returnValue = false;
        
        // do your thing!function checkConnection() {
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
        
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'offLine';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';//Cell 2G connection
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';//Cell 3G connection
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';//Cell 4G connection
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'offLine';
        
        
        if(states[networkState] != 'offLine')
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }
        
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: How do you get this value into iOS for testing purposes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview/15541607#15541607 pleace us the this link to acheive that