# How to make native iOS app response to a click event in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

Say I may have a `UIWebView` displays a page which contains a `link`. When user clicks the link, is it possible to trigger a event to update native `UI`?
For example, when user clicks the link, I want to change the progress value in `UIProgressView`. Is there any way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: What's a `WebUIView` do you mean `UIWebView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview/15541607#15541607  look at this question

Answer (score 2):

Try using this method:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   return TRUE;
}
```

and you can check the navigationType value:

```
enum {
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted,
   UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: protocol method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    // the request variable contains the request the user clicked on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use detecting touch events in the UIWebview by delegate methods below

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches began");
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   NSLog(@"Touches moved");
}
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches ended");
}
- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches cancelled");
}
```

You have to add the UIWebView covering the main view and add a custom class that extends UIWindow to capture touch events.

You can find a step by step tutorial blog [here](http://wyldco.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/).