# Hybrid iOS web and native app event's communication

Tags: ios, iphone, cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking for a hybrid app development strategies. I read about some strategies but one of them is commonly used to put webview in a navigation controller. So the navigation would be done via native app but rest of the visible area would relate to html web.

http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-native-apps/

My question is, is it possible to communicate from javascript to native events. I have reverse of it, as it is implemented in the phonegap but i haven't found javascript functions are calling some native code events.

Please provide some demo links that are implementing apps via hybrid strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I believe your question is already answered and links to external resources are provided within the following SO questions:

[iOS JavaScript bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473582/ios-javascript-bridge)

[How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

[How to invoke Objective C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip)

[Invoke method in objective c code from HTML code using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview)

Disclaimer: I am not sure if this qualifies as an answer, but it seems my reputation does not allow me to write comments, so here we go.