# Html form in UIwebview send back to ios?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

i am trying to pass information between an HTML form and ios i tryed javascrip but it isn't working?

```
        // Init Web View
    UIWebView *webView;
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:boundsRect];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [self addSubview:webView];
    NSString *testArrayString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"testString"];
    NSArray *testArray = [testArrayString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    NSLog(@"%@", testArray);
    [webView release];
    return self;
```

any ideas?

----EDIT----

Ok guys if u only want to make data from a form pass to a ios app you only do this to your webview

```
[webView setDelegate:self];
```

Then you can implement this methods in your program marks

like:

```
    -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {

//implement code to do here

}
```

if you want to capture a for just do a webview shouldStartWithRequest like this:

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIwebView *) webView shouStartWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigation{


//implement code to do afeter the user click the form  don't forget to return YES or NO because it is a BOOL 

}
```

that is how i solve it any question please do tell me i try my best to help

Comment: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` expects you to pass it a javascript snippet which it will evaluate in the web view's context. `testString` is meaningless, it's not javascript, so nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from UIWebView and back to your Objective-C runtime, you need to implement UIWebViewDelegates `webView:shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:` and pass your form-data as parameters in the URL. If you craft all your URL's with a scheme like f.ex. `my-app://?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2`, you can easily filter out the URLs the web view should not load, and return NO.

EDIT:

Added example-code.

```
- (void)initWebView
{
  UIWebView *webView;
  webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:boundsRect];
  webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
  webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
  webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
  webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  webView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL *url = request.URL;
  if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"http://"]) {
    return YES;
  }

  else if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"my-app://"]){
    // Process data from form
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

EDIT2: You are releasing the web view in your initialisation-code. This prevents the delegate-method from being called when you are loading the form-url

EDIT3: See this question for more code-examples: [Invoke method in objective c code from HTML code using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview)

Comment: where can i implement that

Comment: my problem is the HTMl file is local

Comment: This will still work. Local html loads requests with the ```file://``` url-scheme. To send data from the form to the app, you just need to construct a url in the html-file that consists of the data you wish to pass to the Objective-C-runtime, and make sure the web view tries to load that url. Either via a click on an anchor-tag, or with a javascript that sets ```window.location```

Comment: the app is loading the page fine but i still can't pull data from the text box :S

Comment: In java script: ```var url = "my-app://?text=" + document.getElementById("myTextArea").value; window.location = url```

Comment: the javascript doenst change the link

Comment: Without any more code than what you have posted in the original question, it is hard to say what the problem is...

Comment: See latest edit... I think your problem is that you are releasing the web view after the init...

Comment: already deleted that line and still the same :S i am trying to to pass it with the NSURLconnection butt i am still having no luck using html input to pass to a objc-c variable :S