# How can i get the alert in click of submit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

[image]

How can i  get the alert in click of  submit  ?
i am using WebView..

Here is the code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[webView setDelegate:self];

NSString *urlAddress = @“sssssss”;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
      NSString *fragment, *scheme;
      if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
           //1
           [webView stopLoading];
           fragment = [[request URL] fragment];
           scheme = [[request URL] scheme];

           if ([scheme isEqualToString: @"file"] && [self respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)]) {
               [self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)];
               return NO;
           }

           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [request URL]];
      }
      return YES;
}
```

You need to set delegate to WebView.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure @Sudheer Kolasani. What info do you need? is your issue solved?

Comment: How can we know i.e, on click of submit button

Comment: Please check https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/calling-objective-c-methods-from-javascript-in-a-uiwebview/

Comment: the onclick functions did not call it

Comment: A clear description is there here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103192/discussion-between-satish-a-and-sudheer-kolasani).

Answer (score -3):

**1** - Add a IBAction to your submit button.

**2** - Inside the method that gets called use UIAlertController to create a alert that will be displayed when the button is clicked.