# Webview manage in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I making app in Swift 3 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yehrD.png)Firstly login on my app after redirect web view.If i click logout button in web view page I want to redirect back my App.How can i do it ?

Comment: What have you tried — how are you displaying this webview?

Comment: with loadRequest method

Comment: Sure, but you have a view controller that presents a webview (or something)?

Comment: of course WebViewController my present webview i input username and password my app after login on website

Comment: In that case, use `UIWebViewDelegate` to invoke native (Swift or Obj-C) functions/methods from your webview. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15541607/1313761

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WKScriptMessage` and javascript to make a callback to your viewController and exicute native code.

In your viewController:

```
//MARK: WKScriptMessageHandler (callback from js in HTML file)
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage){
    if message.name == "callbackHandler" {
        print(message.body)

        //My function
        if (message.body as AnyObject).contains("myFunctionName"){
            self.playVideo()
        }
    }
}
```

In your HTML file:

```
<!-- JS for Native Application Callbacks -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callNativeApp () {
        //iOS
        try {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage("myFunctionName");
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
        }
    }
</script>
```