# sync an event date from UIWebView to phone Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have an application that loads events from a webview.
There is a SYNC button in the webview and upon tapping it,
I want that event to be saved in the calendar of my phone.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not possible with your current implementation of that web page*, but yes, you can do this, if you have access to that web page and add some code which will [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview) a method in your app than you will have some values which you can pass through that method call and then further write logic to write that event values to the Calendar. Long process but possible.

Comment: is this also possible with Android? I have the idea for the iOS part since i can detect if a certain url will be loaded and choose not to load it.

Comment: I am not sure about android but probably, yes.