# Angular 5 and native IOS/Android communication

Tags: angular, webview, angular5, nativescript

we are building an angular application, which we will embed in an existing  IOS and android application as a webview. I want to create a communication between angular application and native application.

Eg: On certain events like download, angular UI should send some data to native apps to use default app behavior like that ..

From the basic search i found that it can be done by using javascript.

I want to know the best approach to do this(Architecture level), ie communication between angular UI and Native apps.

Comment: Have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801490/4209778 if you are using WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an native iOS / Android app and just like you embed your Angular responsive web app inside, you can communicate using JavaScript Interfaces.

But if you are interested in giving a complete native performance, look & feel for your Angular app, the choice could be NativeScript. You will have to rewrite your HTML components using the cross platform layouts / components that comes out of the box with NativeScript framework, but still you can reuse your Angular Controllers, Models, Services etc.,

**Docs:**

https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/intro

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction

Comment: "communicate using JavaScript Interfaces" .. could you please elaborate how this can be done effectively in angular architecture ?

Comment: This is a quick and simple example of how you can communicate in iOS.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537320/invoke-method-in-objective-c-code-from-html-code-using-uiwebview?answertab=active#tab-top

Similar options are available with Android too.

Comment: In Angular 5 .. we have to write this at any component level or as a common library file ?

Comment: If you have a native app, most of the work will be on the native app side. Web app will have to trigger something which the iOS app can understand and operate accordingly - It has nothing to do with Angular.