# Angular/ HTML5 to iOS WKWebView communication

Tags: html, ios, angular, wkwebview

We are trying to see what is the best option to send some signal **To** iOS `WKWebView` **from** Angular 6, HTML5 project.

Any sample example would be really great.

What we are tyring to do is: we have one button on Angular web page, on click of which it should notify iOS to perform some action.
We load Angular page in iOS `WKWebView`.

With reference to [Angular 5 and native IOS/Android communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591767/angular-5-and-native-ios-android-communication), it is not very clear. It would be great if there are any samples available from both ios and angular side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple provides a mechanism in `WebKit` to post-messages from your HTML to native:

In your HTML page, call:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.messageHandler.postMessage("Pass your data here...");
```

where, `messageHandler` is the name of the message received in your iOS code. `"Pass your data here..."` is the data passed to iOS via `messageHandler` message.

In your iOS code:

Add a message handler using WKUserContentController's `add(_:name:)` method like below:

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "messageHandler")
```

Finally, in your `ViewController` code implement WKScriptMessageHandler's  `userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:` method like:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
     if message.name == "messageHandler" {
          // Your Message handler code goes here...            
     }
```

As per Apple documentation of the `add(_:name:)` method:

> Adding a script message handler with name name
>   causes the JavaScript function window.webkit.messageHandlers.name.postMessage(messageBody) to be defined in all frames in all web views that use the user content controller.

[Apple Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller/1537172-add)

Comment: in angular 8, using window in component.ts file gave error, in html file used `<button onclick="webkit.messageHandlers.sumbitToiOS.postMessage(true)" > CallFromWebToiOS</button>` and it works