# Mobile Safari HTML5 Video Fullscreen detect seeking and seeked events

Tags: mobile, video, safari, fullscreen, seek

Is there any way to bind to and detect the seeking and seeked events while the video is playing in fullscreen and the user scrubs to another video position.

Works fine in an embedded video tag in safari on the desktop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used small JS snippet:
    var lastTimePosition = 0;

```
$("video").on("timeupdate", function(){
                  //Time difference between last event handled and current position
                  var diff = Math.abs(this.currentTime - lastTimePosition);

                  //If difference more that 1 second, handle event (on iOS Safari this event handles 3 times per second. You can increase this parameter to be sure it will handle only on manual seeking
                  if (diff > 1) {
                      window.location = "video://currentTime:" + this.currentTime;
                      console.log("Time:" + this.currentTime);
                  }
                  lastTimePosition = this.currentTime;
});
```

Add this JS snippet on your UIWebView or WKWebView and listen updates. How to get callbacks in Obj-C from JS see
UIWebView: [How to invoke Objective C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip)
WKWebView: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html