# UIWebview Pass URL data to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, uiwebview

I have a little problem when I passing url to javascript

this one is javascript file

```
function geturl(getdata) {

     document.getElementById('test001').src =   getdata;//Iframe don't display data.but if I put url like 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'  is will work. 

}
window.onload = function ()
{
    geturl();
}
```

and Obj-C

```
 NSString * getdata  = @"de";

[subView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"geturl('%@')",[getdata stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];

NSLog(@" getdata = %@",getdata);";
```

and Iframe

```
<iframe id="test001" src="" frameborder="0" hspace="0"  ></iframe>
```

How can I use url from Obj-c to javascript on Iframe. Thanks for any Idea.

---

Update

I try to display data inside getdata
If I  `alert(getdata)` is show correct data.
but If I use this `document.getElementById('test001').src =   'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+getdata;` getdata will show undefined : `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/undefined` something like this. the problem is come from IOS or javascript advice me please.

Answer (score 0):

The output from [NSString stringWithFormat:@"geturl(%@)",[getdata stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];

will be

"geturl(http://someurl.com)"

when it needs to be

"geturl('http://someurl.com')"

Try changing your format string to

@"geturl('%@')"

Comment: Also you might want to try debugging it in a standard browser. If I use that url in chrome I see the error "Refused to display 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." Try using a different url (to a page that doesn't prevent itself being presented in a frame).