# Orientation issue with native pages in Worklight 6.2 and iOS7

Tags: cordova, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a hybrid app using Worklight Studio 6.2 for iOS. The application should be forced to landscape orientation. In iOS 7, when I call a native page, the orientation defaults to portrait even though I have set the view controller to landscape. The orientation works correctly for iOS 8.

I tried to set the native page to landscape using the following code but it's not working:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:* We also have a fix for the issue when using `WL.NativePage.show`.
You will need to open a PMR in order to receive a version with this fix.

---

It is strange that it's not working in iOS 7 but does in iOS 8.  If you want you can [open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) to have the Worklight development team look into it.

That said, the orientation does work correctly when using the `SendAction` API, available starting Worklight 6.2.
[The SendAction API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_sending_actions_js_to_native.html?lang=en) basically allows you to send a 'command' - an action, to the native side and with this action you can do whatever you want. For example, open a View Controller of your own that you will have full control over it, which is much better than what `WL.NativePage.show` allows you.

The below example is based on the [NativePagesInHyridApp sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/UsingNativePagesInHybridAppsProject.zip) from the [Getting Started page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid).

1. In common\js\main.js you send an action where required:

   ```
   function openNativePage(){
       ...
       ...
       WL.App.sendActionToNative("openViewController");
   }
   ```
2. In NativePagesInHybridApp.h, add the `WLActionReceiver` protocol to the interface,  i.e.:

   ```
   @interface MyViewController : MyViewController <WLInitWebFrameworkDelegate, WLActionReceiver> {

   }
   ```
3. In NativePagesInHybridApp.m, add the implementation:

   ```
   @implementation MyAppDelegate

   -(void)onActionReceived:(NSString *)action withData:(NSDictionary*) data{
       NSLog(@"onActionReceived :: %@", action);

       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addViewController) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];    
   }

   -(void)addViewController{
       HelloNative *helloNativeViewController = [[HelloNative alloc] init];
       [self.window.rootViewController addChildViewController:helloNativeViewController];
       [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:helloNativeViewController.view];
   }

   ...
   ...
   ```

Now, when you launch the app and click the button, the generated view controller will be displayed - in landscape as well.

In the above example, a view controller is implemented in code, but you could create your own with a XIB or one [created in Storyboard](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/integrating_a_worklight_based_ios_app_with_xcode_storyboard?lang=en) and call it up...