# Native App pass session to webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to make my app's login page native, but after user login they would be redirect to the webview. basically the app is webview except the login page. Is there anyway to pass the login sessino between native app and webview?

PS: xcode ios

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the below way to pass details in native and webview html page.

1. Write detail in file.
2. It can be directly accessed in native using file concept.
3. For webview you need to write plugin to access native functionalities like cordova plugins

OR

Javascript call [How to invoke Objective C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip)

Comment: Thanks  i will look into that