# How to call Javascript method from UIViewController in native iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm making a simple call to my Javascript function and sending a variable/string in the same. But the same function is not getting called in javascript.

```
NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setLegend('%@')",result];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
```

In Javascript

```
function setLegend(lStr)
{
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: Has the web view been added to view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes it is in the view hierarchy

Comment: Check this link [How to invoke Objective C method from Javascript and send back data to Javascript in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip). hope this will help you.

Comment: check your web view delegates for error.

Comment: where u are calling this .. do it in webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: I'm using it in webViewDidFinishLoad only.

Comment: NSString *legendStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sendLegend()"];
     [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:legendStr];