# How can I detect when an element is visible after loading website in WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to load a transit website so I can scrape the stop times for a given stop. After I load the url, the stop times are loaded in a bit later dynamically through javascript. My goal is to detect the presence of elements with a class of "stop-time". If these elements are present in the html I can then parse the html. But before I can parse the html I have to wait for these elements with class of "stop-time" to appear. I read through a bunch of other SO questions but I couldn't quite piece it together. I am implementing the didReceive message function but I'm not really sure how to load in the javascript I need to detect the presence of the elements (elements with class of "stop-time"). I successfully injected some javascript to prevent the location permission popup from showing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    let scriptSource = "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, options) {}; navigator.geolocation.watchPosition = function(success, error, options) {}; navigator.geolocation.clearWatch = function(id) {};"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    contentController.addUserScript(script)

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    self.view = self.webView!

    loadStopTimes("https://www.website.com/stop/1000")
}

func loadStopTimes(_ busUrl: String) {
    let urlString = busUrl
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView?.load(urlRequest)
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if(message.name == "stopTimesLoaded") {
        // stop times now present so take the html and parse the stop times
    }
}
```

Comment: If "stop-time" elements loaded with scripts, you can call method in your app from your javascript when load completed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826792/how-to-invoke-objective-c-method-from-javascript-and-send-back-data-to-javascrip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all You need to inject next script to detect appearence of elements via mutations observer:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log('mutation.type = ' + mutation.type);
      for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
        if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.className == 'stop-time') {
            var content = node.textContent;
            console.log('  "' + content + '" added');
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.stopTimesLoaded.postMessage({ data: content });
        }
      }
    });
  });
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Then You need to subscribe for event 'stopTimesLoaded':

```
contentController.add(self, name: "stopTimesLoaded")
```

And finally add code to process data in

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)
```

Comment: I'm now trying to detect the presence of the container with class "stoproutes-results". I tried changing node.className == 'stop-time' to node.className == 'stoproutes-results' but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Are You sure that You changed message handler for registered in content controller?
window.webkit.messageHandlers can send messages only to registered events via contentController.add